# Socket connect method doesn't work when in separate function

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I have the following code that connects to a server successfully:

```
response = connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(address));
if (response < 0) {
    printf("Failed to connect\n");
    exit(1);
} else {
  printf("Connected\n");
}
```

However, if I move this code into it's own function and call it with `connect_to_server(socket_fd, &address)`, the connection fails.

```
void * connect_to_server(int socket_fd, struct sockaddr_in *address) {
    int response = connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(address));
    if (response < 0) {
        printf("Failed to connect\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
      printf("Connected\n");
    }
}
```

From what I can tell, I am passing arguments correctly here, so I don't know what the problem is.  I've done basically the exact same thing for separating out a `send_to` method that uses the same `socket_fd` and `address` variables.

I assume I'm making some kind of syntax error, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: You should call `perror()`, or print the result of `strerror()`, when you get a failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
void * connect_to_server(int socket_fd, struct sockaddr_in *address) {
```

you pass in a pointer already.

And here

```
int response = connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &address, sizeof(address));
```

you again take an address, to pass to `connect()`, namely the address of the pointer. Also the size passed in is the size of the pointer not what it is pointing to.

You do not want this, but pass on the pointer as received, along with the size it is pointing to like this:

```
int response = connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) address, sizeof(*address));
```

Or even nicer (as `sizeof` is an operator not a function) do:

```
int response = connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) address, sizeof *address);
```